# Can any ssd drive be put in an ibm thinkpad x31

Tags: ssd, thinkpad

I've heard one of the ways to breath new life into an old machine is to put an ssd drive in it. So I've got this x31 and I have no idea what kind of interface the drive has, but it's a 40 gig drive, and 40 gig ssd drives are cheap, but I don't know what to buy that will plug in correctly. Anybody know?

Answer (score 2):

I think not all. Only SSD with PATA interface, for example [Transcend](http://www.transcendusa.com/Products/ModDetail.asp?ModNo=164&LangNo=0&Func1No=1&Func2No=171).

Answer (score 2):

There are/were some SSDs with PATA (IDE) interfaces, but it may be hard finding one these days.  I also seem to remember there being drives which you populate yourself with SD flash cards.  I doubt any of these drives would give that much of a performance boost.

I have an X31, although it is no longer my main laptop.  I fitted a 7,200rpm Hitachi drive a few years ago, which sped it up.  If you want to speed up yours, make sure you are using as much RAM as possible (2GB, IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

I have an X31 with this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Startech-inch-Compact-Flash-Adapter/dp/B001E25LOS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327248426&sr=8-1 and the fastest compactflash card I could find (90MB/s write) and the machine is amazingly fast. Word of advice though, be sure to optimize your operating system for SSD after installation, otherwise the constant writing might wear out your flash memory prematurely.

Comment: suggestions on what to do to optimize for ssd? No swap would be good, but I don't see that as an option as there's only 2 gig in the machine. other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have found these things for $8...

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Secure-2-5-44-Pin-IDE-Male-SD-SDHC-MMC-Adapter-Converter-/280796285857?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4160c34ba1#ht_3569wt_1168